# Switch Live Wallpapers Automatically without Root

Tags: 8.1-oreo, live-wallpaper

I am wondering whether there is any way to switch between like wallpapers on my Pixel 2 without rooting it as it is a Verizon phone with a locked bootloader. I have 2 live wallpapers I like and would like for then to automatically switch... I've tried using Tasker and Automate, but both require root. If there is any way please let me know. Thank you!

Answer (score -1):

You can try smart wallpaper from playstore 
I've tried on static wallpaper 
But it's worth a try on live wallpaper

Comment: Welcome to Android Enthusiasts! This post does not contain enough information to be considered an answer. How did it solve the issue? Where to find it? What are the steps to perform?